# Show tree of directory with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to show a tree of a directory in a frame and open a file in another frame using angularjs i didn't find any solution i used angular directive ui-ace to show the data but i can't show a data from a file selected!

```
 <div ui-ace="{
      useWrapMode : true,
      showGutter: false,
      theme:'twilight',
      mode: 'markdown'
 }" ng-model="aceModel"></div>
```

and this is my controller

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.ace'])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.aceModel ='some data';
 }]);
```

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: The information you have provide is not sufficient enough, please provide more detail and a little more code.